# Converter resultado de string.match() em string?

Tags: string, regex, typescript

Como posso converter o retorno do método `match()` em string? Por exemplo:

```
var value:string = ">>>> Ola"
var result:string = value.match(/\w+/g)
```

O exemplo acima dá erro na variável `result`. Já tentei colocar dessa forma com `.toString()`, mas não dá certo:

```
var result:string = value.match(/\w+/g).toString()
```

Como posso pegar o valor da regex e transformar em uma string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você usou a [*flag* `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters), o método `match` [retorna um array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value) contendo todos os trechos encontrados (exceto os [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), mas como a sua regex não tem isso, então tudo bem).

Então no fundo, tudo se resume a transformar um array em string. E aí depende, tem várias formas de fazer.

No seu caso específico, se você "sabe" que só vai ter uma ocorrência, pode simplesmente pegar o primeiro elemento do array:

```js
let value = ">>>> Ola";
let result = value.match(/\w+/g);
if (result) {
    console.log(result[0]);
}
```

Eu verifico se `result` é válido, pois quando não é encontrado nenhum *match*, o método `match` retorna `null` (e nesse caso, não há o que imprimir).

---

Se há a possibilidade de retornar mais de um *match*, aí basta percorrer o array e obter as strings uma a uma:

```js
let value = ">>>> Ola, mundo";
let result = value.match(/\w+/g);
if (result) {
    result.forEach(s => console.log(s));
}
```

Ou ainda usar [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), por exemplo, para mostrar todas as strings concatenadas de uma vez:

```js
let value = ">>>> Ola, mundo";
let result = value.match(/\w+/g);
if (result) {
    console.log(result.join(', '));
}
```

Enfim, uma vez tendo o array com as strings encontradas, você decide a melhor forma de mostrá-las.

Comment: Ola, só consigo pegar a string na saída? Por exemplo via console? Tem como declarar uma variável com o valor da regex?

Comment: @Isaac Seria isso `let valor = result.join(', ')`? Assim, `valor` é uma string e vc pode fazer o que quiser com ela. Não sei se entendi direito o que vc quer...

Comment: É isso mesmo, mas no TypeScript não tem o método .join() no match(), me corrija se eu estiver errado

Comment: @Isaac Ué, `match` retorna o que então, não é um array? Acabei de testar aqui e funcionou...

Answer (score 0):

O retorno da função match() é um array, sendo assim, pode ser convertido para string da seguinte forma:

```js
var value = ">>>> Ola"
var result = value.match(/\w+/g) !== null
    ? value.match(/\w+/g).join(' ') 
    : '';

alert(result);
```

Dessa forma, o result concatenaria todos os matchs com um espaço, caso haja necessidade de substituir o espaço por algum caractere, basta mudar o texto dentro da função join.

```js
var value = ">>>> Ola >>>>> teste"
var result = value.match(/\w+/g) !== null
    ? value.match(/\w+/g).join('|||') 
    : '';

alert(result);
```

Comment: Está dando erro de 'Object is possibly 'null''. Só está funcionando no JavaScript

Comment: vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: O problema de Object is possibly 'null' ocorria pois o retorno da função match podia ser null, fiz um IF ternário para que quando for null, atribua '' à string